Why would David not drink the water?
We see in 2 Samuel 23 that David expresses how thirsty he is:

15 And David had a craving and said, “Oh that someone would give me
water to drink from the well of Bethlehem which is by the gate!” 16 So
the three mighty men forced their way into the camp of the
Philistines, and drew water from the well of Bethlehem which was by
the gate, and carried it and brought it to David. Yet he would not
drink it, but poured it out as an offering to the Lord; 17 and he
said, “Far be it from me, Lord, that I would do this! Should I drink
the blood of the men who went at the risk of their lives?” So he would
not drink it. These things the three mighty men did.

After having expressed his thirst aloud, David's men risk their lives to attain water. David then does not drink the water that they risked their lives for.
What is the reason for this?

Wouldn't pouring out the water as an offering to the Lord be a greater honor to the "mighty men" than if David had drunk the water?

This question is answered by the commentaries as follows:
Ellicott

(16) Poured it out unto the Lord.—The brave act of the three heroes
shows strikingly the personal power of David over his followers and
the enthusiasm with which he inspired them. Yet, on the other hand,
David would not suffer his own longing to be gratified by the hazard
of men’s lives. Taking the water, therefore, he “poured it out unto
the Lord.” The word is the technical term for the sacrificial
libation, and David assimilated his act to a sacrifice by a solemn
consecration of this dangerously won water to the Lord.

Cambridge Commentary

poured it out unto the Lord The sacrificial term for pouring out a drink-offering or libation (Genesis 35:14, &c.). “That which had been
won by the lives of those three gallant chiefs was too sacred for him
to drink, but it was on that very account deemed by him as worthy to
be consecrated in sacrifice to God, as any of the prescribed offerings
of the Levitical ritual. Pure Chivalry and pure Religion there formed
an absolute union.” Stanley’s Lect. II. 54.

Benson

(17) Is not this the blood . . .?—The Hebrew here is simply an
interrogative exclamation, “the blood of the men?” but in 1Chronicles
11:19 the text reads, “Shall I drink the blood of these men?” &c., and
so the LXX. and Vulg. translate here. To David the water gained only
at the risk of life, “seemed the very blood in which the life resides”
(Leviticus 17:10-11).


That's a very interesting note by Benson. As if David saw the water as too sacred to drink because it represented the lives and blood of his men. I see the honor in it. Thank you for the answer. +1.

I would strengthen the Cambridge version by observing that the risk-taking was already a form of sacrifice, and he evidently recognised how much hubris would be involved in accepting it for his own benefit. Therefore he diverted it back to the Lord.

@StephenDisraeli - good point - agreed.

+1 ... I see that the classical Jewish commentators generally agree with this. Personally I can't help but wonder if David felt that actual blood may have contaminated the water.

Back in those days, the people of God had had instilled into them the fact that life is a sacred gift from God - that he created mankind in his image and likeness. In Genesis the way blood was to be viewed was first shown. When Cain killed his brother, God declared,

"The voice of thy brother's blood cries unto me from the ground. And
now art thou cursed from the earth, which hath opened her mouth to
receive thy brother's blood from thy hand." Genesis 4:3-12 A.V.

Nobody witnessed that first killing (apart from God who, nevertheless, spoke as if the ground had cried out in notification.) And that spilled blood could not be ignored by God.
Then, later, in the days of Noah, God made a covenant with him, his family, and all humanity when they came out of the ark and made a sacrifice of animals, which required their blood to be shed. Then God brought blood into the covenant by saying man could now eat animal flesh:

"But flesh with the life thereof, which is the blood thereof, shall ye
not eat. And surely your blood of your lives will I require; at the
hand of every beast will I require it, and at the hand of man; at the
hand of every man's brother will I require the life of man. Whoso
sheddeth man's blood, by man shall his blood be shed; for in the image
of God made he man." Genesis 9:3-6 A.V.

When, much later, the law of Moses was given, and the death penalty declared for murderers, even the unintentional manslayer still had to flee for his life to one of the ten cities of refuge. There he had to stay until the death of the High Priest. If he did not reach the city before the next of kin of the victim caught up with him, he would forfeit his life. If he left the city of refuge before the death of the High Priest, the next of kin had to right to kill him.
King David knew all this. The sanctity of life, and the way blood symbolized God-given life, was the powerful factor in causing him to view the water presented to him as if it was the life-blood of the men who risked their lives getting it. As it was a sin to drink blood (Leviticus 19:26), but blood had to be poured out on to the ground, so David poured out that which was symbolically representative of those mens' lives.
